# Trying to add image in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying add a photo in the SQL Management Studio 2018. But it tells to use bulk load statement. On the Stackoverflow I saw some steps that may help me. It was recommended to go to the login->security->properties and  activate 'bulkadmin'. This operation failed saying that it is not enough permission.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/) help?

Comment: I am getting this error "Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 105 [Batch Start Line 2]
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 5
You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.
Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 [Batch Start Line 6]
The configuration option 'Ole Automation Procedures' does not exist, or it may be an advanced optMsg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 105 [Batch Start Line 2]
User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: and for importing iamge this "Msg 262, Level 14, State 18, Procedure usp_ImportImage, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'." error is getting

Comment: And this for export procedure "Msg 262, Level 14, State 18, Procedure usp_ExportImage, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'."

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to grant the `bulkadmin` Server Role to a Login, the login you are using to make this change will need to either have `CONTROL` permissions on the Login, or the `ALTER ANY LOGIN` permission on the SQL Server itself.

The easiest solution if possible would be for your own Login to be granted the `sysadmin` Server Role by another Login with the necessary permissions to do this.

More information about Server-Level Roles from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017).